# Is that reported speech or something else?

Tags: reported-speech

I saw this [headline in a newspaper](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/02/12/politics/biden-impeachment-trial/index.html): "Biden says he's anxious to see what Republicans do in impeachment trial".

Could you say is that some sort of "[headlinese](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese)" or it just a correct form of the sentence?

I mean that this sentence should be written as a reported speech like "Biden said ..." and so on.

Comment: Yes, reported speech. Add "in **the** impeachment trial," to change it from headlinese.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay. I meant, is that correct to use the present simple in the reported speech? Is it correct to use such a form of the sentence in the real life? Or we should use something like "Biden said ..."?

Comment: It's more like the historical present, in that no one cares what was **once said**. Imagine that Biden says X at noon, and the news broadcasts it at 12:01. He *said* it at noon, but they will announce it as "says X." It's understandable that way. Not just speech, but actions, too. Man lands on moon. Congress votes No. Snow falls on much of the Urals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [*What is the difference between "he was saying", "he says" and "he said"?*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/222508/what-is-the-difference-between-he-was-saying-he-says-and-he-said) See also [*Omission of That and which*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/221295/omission-of-that-and-which).

Comment: Thanks a lot @YosefBaskin! Really, it looks like the "historical present tense". The definition that I found describes it as "Speakers use this form because it makes the story sound more immediate, more exciting, and less formal." Probably, newspaper headliners like use this tense too.

https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-reported-speech-and-historic-present-tense/4010017.html